# how to for each item in a list create class objects by passing parameters from functions

Tags: python, oop

defined few functions (not induced body of the functions to simplify  question here)

```
def policyname(i):
    retrun policyname
def policytype(i):
    retrun policytype
def active(i):
    retrun active
def backupselection(i):
    retrun backupselection
```

defined a list -

```
clients = ['winwebint16', 'winwebtpie03', 'winwebtpie04', 'winwtsdt08', 'winwtsmwg03', 'winwtsqnr03', 'winwtswrl37', 'winwtswrl60', 'winwtswrl62', 'winwtswrl63', 'winwtswrl75', 'winwtszsim03', 'winwww0016','winsbk0100', 'winsbk0100a0', 'winsbk0100a1', 'winsbk0101', 'iinf065', 'iinf130', 'iinf185', 'iinf2126', 'inbf005', 'inis001', 'ipdataisbic01', 'ipdataisbic02', 'ipdataispre01', 'ipdataispre02', 'iproip02', 'isis002', 'isyn002', 'isyn006', 'isyn011', 'isyn012','isyn014', 'isyn038', 'isyn039', 'isyn040', 'mu2ssql1001', 'mu2ssql1003', 'macrsz0001', 'macrsz0005']
```

defined a class -

```
 class client():
    def __init__(self,policyname,policytype,active,backupselection):
        self.policyname = policyname
        self.policytype = policytype
        self.active = active
        self.backupselection = backupselection
```

For each item in clients list create class objects by passing parameters from functions.
Is below code is correct ?

```
for i in clients:
    i = client(policyname(i),policytype(i),active(i),backupselection(i))
```

with above code, will i be able to access specific class objects like ?

```
print(winwebint16.policyname)
print(winwebint16.policytype)
print(winwebint16.active)
print(winwebint16.backupselection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Classnames should be capital letter but that's just convention. Further you have a problem with the `for` loop

```
for i in clients:
    i = client(policyname(i),policytype(i),active(i),backupselection(i))
```

The created client is not visible outside of the `for loop` scope, so you might wanna add them to some kind of `list` or `dict`

```
client_list: dict = {}
for i in clients:
   client_list[i] = client(policyname(i),policytype(i),active(i),backupselection(i))
```

you should then be able to print like

```
print(client_list['winwebint16'].policyname)
```

Comment: I understand that we can't use variable i outside of for loop but will that work if i define functions within for loop. I did not want to use dictionary

Comment: any other way of doing this with class & objects

Comment: What is the benefit of having objects with specific naming automatically created?

Comment: I could do that, posting my answer, just review.

Answer (score 0):

This really worked for me :

```
clients = ['669165933', '963881480', '341417157', '514321792', '115456712', '547995746', '135425221', '871543967', '770463311', '616607081', '814711606', '939825713']

policynames = ['Tuvalu', 'Grenada', 'Russia', 'Sao Tome and Principe', 'Rwanda', 'Solomon Islands', 'Angola', 'Burkina Faso', 'Republic of the Congo', 'Senegal', 'Kyrgyzstan', 'Cape Verde']

policytypes = ['Offline', 'Online', 'Offline', 'Online', 'Offline', 'Online', 'Offline', 'Online', 'Offline', 'Online', 'Online', 'Offline']

actives = ['Baby Food', 'Cereal', 'Office Supplies', 'Fruits', 'Office Supplies', 'Baby Food', 'Household', 'Vegetables', 'Personal Care', 'Cereal', 'Vegetables', 'Clothes']

backupselections = ['H', 'C', 'L', 'C', 'L', 'C', 'M', 'H', 'M', 'H', 'H', 'H']

def policyname(i):
        return policynames[i]
def policytype(i):
        return policytypes[i]
def active(i):
        return actives[i]
def backupselection(i):
        return backupselections[i]

class client():
    def __init__(self,policyname,policytype,active,backupselection):
        self.policyname = policyname
        self.policytype = policytype
        self.active = active
        self.backupselection = backupselection
        
for i in range(0,len(clients)):
    i = client(policyname(i),policytype(i),active(i),backupselection(i))
    print(i.policyname,i.policytype,i.active,i.backupselection)

Tuvalu Offline Baby Food H
Grenada Online Cereal C
Russia Offline Office Supplies L
Sao Tome and Principe Online Fruits C
Rwanda Offline Office Supplies L
Solomon Islands Online Baby Food C
Angola Offline Household M
Burkina Faso Online Vegetables H
Republic of the Congo Offline Personal Care M
Senegal Online Cereal H
Kyrgyzstan Online Vegetables H
Cape Verde Offline Clothes H
```

**But still I can't print**

```
print(669165933.policyname)

  File "<ipython-input-20-72da397c032b>", line 1
    print(669165933.policyname)
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Yes because the `i` from `i = client(policyname(i),policytype(i),active(i),backupselection(i))` has nothing to do with your foor loop variable `i`. There is no object `669165933`

Comment: should I create len(clients) number of classes to achieve this ? to get print(669165933.policyname)... how can achieve this

Comment: how can we create objects with name same as each items in list clients